# Some motivation on the Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Finding **the wave and heat equations** provide two important (physical)  motivation to study the Fourier series. Does there exist any other real-world sample that determines the necessity of studying the Fourier series (particularly discrete Fourier series)?

Comment: Signal processing?

Comment: Any system of linear differential equations. You won't find ***any*** branch of engineering or science which does not have plenty of applications to those. More importantly it paves the way for other integral transforms and theory of linear functional operators.

Comment: @mathreadler Could you please let me know (any reference) where the Fourier series intervenes on the theory of linear functional operators as well as integral transforms?

Comment: Any introductory course on transform theory and functional analysis should get you started.